# What's mistake I am doing with this ternary operator?

Tags: php, operators

```
function get_status($data) {
    return ($data->cm_status == 'Y') ? 'Active' :
        ($data->cm_status == 'N') ? 'Inactive' : '-';    
}
```

I should get `Active` if `$data->cm_status` is `Y`

I should get `Inactive` if `$data->cm_status` is `N`

I should get `-` if `$data->cm_status` is anything else

But actually in all case I am getting `Inactive`

What is the mistake I am doing?

*references to your answers appreciated*

Comment: Always wrap each deeper condtions in `()`   `false ? 'foo' : ( true ? 'bar' :'bobby' )`, its the save way

Comment: In my opinion, using nested ternary operators should be avoyded, specially if you care about readability. You will help yourself and other potential developers if you use clearly written if/else/switch/case instead.

Answer (score 4):

You need to wrap the inner ternary operator in brackets for the results to be produced correctly, like this

```
function get_status($data) {
    return $data->cm_status == 'Y' ? 'Active' :
        ($data->cm_status == 'N' ? 'Inactive' : '-');
}
```

A more readable approach could be to use a `switch` instead, using nested ternary operators could easily confuse and cause more chaos than it solves. A `switch` would look like this

```
function get_status($data) {
    switch ($data->cm_status) {
        case "Y":
            return 'Active';
        case "N":
            return 'Inactive';
        default:
            return '-';
    }
}
```

This also assumes that the input would always be upper-case, you could add additional code to compare regardless if its upper or lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

In case of nested ternary operator the composite one should be inside a couple of brackets. So try this;

```
function get_status($data) {
    return ($data->cm_status == 'Y') ? 'Active' :(($data->cm_status == 'N') ? 'Inactive' : '-')
}
```

Notice the "()" in second ternary conditional operator.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
function get_status($data) {
    return ($data->cm_status == 'Y') ? 'Active' :
        (($data->cm_status == 'N') ? 'Inactive' : '-');    
}
```